# Most efficient way to upgrade to React Native 0.60.5 from 0.59.2

Tags: react-native, updates

I am currently at React Native version 0.59.2 but I would like to update my project to 0.60.5. I noticed that it now uses autolinking (pods for iOS) for the installed dependencies as opposed to using the react-native link(ing) anymore.

What would be the most efficient way to upgrade to this latest version? Would I delink all the dependencies I currently have?
How would I generate the Podfile, and do I need to include all the dependencies in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the proper way to upgrade your project's react-native version

**please follow this:-** https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/